# Pandas: select value from random column on each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

Suppose I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [4, 5, 6],
    'c': [7, 8, 9]
})
```

```
    a   b   c
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
```

I want to generate a new `pandas.Series` so that the values of this series are selected, row by row, from a random column in the DataFrame. So, a possible output for that would be the series:

```
0    7
1    2
2    9
dtype: int64
```

(where in row 0 it randomly chose 'c', in row 1 it randomly chose 'a' and in row 2 it randomly chose 'c' again).

I know this can be done by iterating over the rows and using `random.choice` to choose each row, but iterating over the rows not only has bad performance but also is "unpandonic", so to speak. Also, df.sample(axis=1) would choose whole columns, so all of them would be chosen from the same column, which is not what I want. Is there a better way to do this with vectorized pandas methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be something like:

```
pd.Series([np.random.choice(i,1)[0] for i in df.values])
```

Comment: If you need to make many columns like this, I found this to be much more efficient: `newdf = df.apply(lambda row : row.sample(n=10000, replace=True).values, axis=1, result_type="expand")`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a fully vectorized solution. Note however that it does not use Pandas methods, but rather involves operations on the underlying numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

indices = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(df.columns)), len(df), replace=True)
```

Example output is `[1, 2, 1]` which corresponds to `['b', 'c', 'b']`.

Then use this to slice the numpy array:

```
df['random'] = df.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), indices]
```

Results:

```
   a  b  c  random
0  1  4  7       7
1  2  5  8       5
2  3  6  9       9
```

Comment: Could you explain what this part of the syntax is doing `[np.arange(len(df)), indices]` ? I'm having trouble googling it.

Comment: Also your answer gives very different distributions on my data than the answer from @jfaccioni, in ways that make me think something is wrong with this answer (I get drastically smaller means with your answer). It does run much faster though.

Comment: @JosephGarvin - that syntax is slicing the 2D array, using two sequences of the same length representing row indices and column indices. Here, `np.arange(len(df))` is the row indices - in the example above it is just `[0, 1, 2]`. The randomly selected column indices are in the `indices` variable (`[1, 2, 1]` in the example). Slicing with `[0, 1, 2]` and `[1, 2, 1]` returns the values at (0, 1), (1, 2) and (2, 1).

Comment: @JosephGarvin - I've looped over my solution a few million times and am not seeing anything unusual in the results, at least using the small example data set in this question. If you can share a dataset (or let me know how I can generate one) that shows my solution giving different results from the looped solutions I'll be interested to see.

Answer (score 2):

This does the job (using the built-in module `random`):

```
ddf = df.apply(lambda row : random.choice(row.tolist()), axis=1)
```

or using `pandas sample`:

```
ddf = df.apply(lambda row : row.sample(), axis=1)
```

Both have the same behaviour. `ddf` is your Series.

Comment: note that #1 can be simplified to `df.apply(random.choice, axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame(
    df.values[range(df.shape[0]), 
                   np.random.randint(
                       0, df.shape[1], size=df.shape[0])])
```

output

```
    0
0   4
1   5
2   9
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably still going to need to iterate through each row while selecting a random value in each row - whether you do it explicitly with a for loop or implicitly with whatever function you decide to call.

You can, however, simplify the to a single line using a list comprehension, if it suits your style:

```
result = pd.Series([random.choice(pd.iloc[i]) for i in range(len(df))])
```