# Select Random Value from Pandas list column for each row ensuring that value don't get picked again

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame below

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'poc': ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    'school': ["school1", "school2", "school3", "school4"],
    'volunteers': [["sam", "mat", "ali", "mike", "guy", "john"],
                   ["sam", "mat", "ali", "mike"],
                   ["rose", "sam", "mike", "jorge"],
                   ["susan", "jack", "alex", "mat", "mike"]]
})
```

| poc | school | volunteers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | school1 | ['sam', 'mat', 'ali', 'mike', 'guy', 'john'] |
| b | school2 | ['sam', 'mat', 'ali', 'mike'] |
| c | school3 | ['rose', 'sam', 'mike', 'jorge'] |
| d | school4 | ['susan', 'jack', 'alex', 'mat', 'mike'] |

I need to create a new column that has a random pick from the volunteers column to select 1 volunteer for each school ensuring that the same volunteer doesn't get picked twice.

So far I have tried:

```
import random

df["random_match"] = [random.choice(x) for x in df["volunteers"]]
```

but this just gives me a random volunteer without ensuring it is not repeated.

Comment: @HenryEcker volunteers is the column in the dataframe that contain a list of names like so [sam, mat, ali, mike, guy, john] as the screenshot shows

Comment: So you want to pick a value from the nested list at random, but prevent that name from being later duplicated in the same column.

Comment: This is an interesting problem to solve. Never thought of this situation. Thanks for posting the question. Have you tried any solution yet? If so, can you please share your work.

Comment: You can try this approach but it will not guarantee if the volunteer was picked earlier .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57201812/pandas-select-value-from-random-column-on-each-row

Comment: I updated the question to include the code and what I have tried so far

Comment: @HenryEcker yes! I also updated the question to include the code as you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
from random import sample

df["pick"] = ""

for i, list_of_volunteers in enumerate(df["volunteers"].values):
    for volunteer in sample(list_of_volunteers, len(list_of_volunteers)):
        if volunteer not in df["pick"].values:
            df.loc[i, "pick"] = volunteer
            break

print(df)
# Outputs
  poc   school                        volunteers   pick
0   a  school1  [sam, mat, ali, mike, guy, john]    mat
1   b  school2             [sam, mat, ali, mike]   mike
2   c  school3          [rose, sam, mike, jorge]  jorge
3   d  school4    [susan, jack, alex, mat, mike]   jack
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Just accumulate what you have seen so far and remove it from the set of available choices. I am assuming a default value of NAN if nothing fits.

```
df["random_match"] = pd.NA
already_picked = set()
for row_idx in range(len(df)):
    available_group = set(df.iloc[row_idx]["volunteers"]) - already_picked
    if len(available_group) > 0:
        chosen_name = random.sample(available_group, 1)[0]
        df.loc[row_idx, 'random_match'] = chosen_name
        already_picked.add(chosen_name)
```